# Graph theory planar involving graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Is there such graph that it is not planar but if we remove any of its edges it become planar ?
if there is such one can you please introduce it to us ?

Comment: $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are both prototypical examples of this.  Kuratowski's theorem states that if a graph has $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a graph minor then it is planar.  $K_5\setminus e$ for any edge $e$ clearly does not have $K_5$ as a graph minor nor $K_{3,3}$ and so is thus planar.

Comment: I slightly misspoke, if it has $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ then it is **non**-planar of course.  Also worth mentioning is that it is a biconditional, if it does not have $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor then it is planar